# Can we define a product for almost convergent sequences?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, real-numbers

A sequence $x_n$ is almost convergent if
$$
\exists L\in\mathbb R:
\forall\varepsilon\in\mathbb R:
\exists p_0\in\mathbb N:
\forall p>p_0:
\forall n\in\mathbb N: 
\left| L-\frac1p\sum_{i=n}^{n+p-1}x_i \right| \leq \varepsilon \\
$$
The condition can be rewritten as
$$
p(L-\varepsilon) \leq \sum_{i=n}^{n+p-1}x_i \leq p(L+\varepsilon)
$$
and with that it seems obvious that the sum of two almost convergent sequences with limits $L_1$ and $L_2$ will almost converge to $L_1+L_2$.

On the other hand, if we consider the product (element-wise) of two sequences, things are more complicated. If we take for example $x_n = y_n = (-1)^n$, we can prove that both almost converge to 0, on the other hand $x_n \cdot y_n = 1$. So my question is: can we define the product in a different way so that the result is a sequence that almost converges to the product of the limits of the input sequences?

To provide some more context, I am nostly interested in almost convergent sequences of integers and am lookin for a form of product that would be also a sequence of integers. The larger problem I am trying to solve is to define the reals almost convergent sequences of integers.

**Update**: Based on some simple examples that I did by hand, it seems that the following product could be a candidate:
$$
c_n = \frac1{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^n a_i \cdot b_{n-i}
$$
I am however unable so far to prove that this product is almost convergent whenver $a_n$ and $b_n$ are.

Comment: Shouldn't the lower bound of the sum in the definition of almost convergence be $i=n$ instead of $i=p$?

Comment: @MartinR Indeed, good observation, stupid typo on my side, thank you for pointing it out, I edited the question to fix it. It is however just a typo and not the reason I can't find a proof of almost convergence for my product.